# Probability that a node loses an edge in the Barabási-Albert (BA) model with removal of edges

Tags: probability, probability-theory, graph-theory, random-graphs, network

I'm following the book *Networks* by Mark Newman. He considers an extension to the BA model where edges are removed uniformly at random. He computes the probability that a particular node $i$ loses an edge when a single edge is removed from the network to be
$$ p_i = \frac{2k_i}{\sum_j k_j}, $$
where $k_i$ is the degree of node $i$ and he says *the factor two coming from the two ends of the edge*.

I understand why the probability is proportional to the node degree, because the number of edges attached to a node is the degree (in the case there are no self-loops). 
What I don't understand is **why there is a factor $2$**. It seems to me this probability is not properly normalized, as $\sum_i p_i = 2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the events "Node $i$ loses an edge" are not disjoint - whenever an edge is removed, **two** nodes will lose an edge, so it makes sense that the probabilities will sum to 2.
Regarding the factor of $2$ in the $p_i$ formula, there are $\frac{\sum_{j} {k_j}}{2}$ edges, and there are $k_i$ edges with an end at node $i$, so the probability that such an edge will be chosen is $$\frac{k_i}{\frac{\sum_j {k_i}}{2}} = \frac{2k_i}{\sum_j {k_j}}$$

Comment: Ok thanks! I also understood now why you can consider the *factor two coming from the two ends of the edge*, as you can remove an edge from node $i$ either by removing a "stub" from that node (there are $k_i$ of them) or by removing the "stub" from the other end of the edge (which sum also to $k_i$).